# Table View: right to left swipe to delete does not show up - swift 3

Tags: swift, tableview, swift3, ios10

I've built a simple toDoList app with Swift 3. Now I want to be able to delete my items from a `TableView` by swiping from right to left. This code is what I've found. But **nothing** happens when I swipe to the left.

---

**CODE:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return toDoList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = toDoList[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}



//
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        toDoList.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        UserDefaults.standard.set(toDoList, forKey: "toDoList")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .delete
}
```

---

This still does not work. **Nothing happens when I swipe to the left**. The to do List itself is working. I can add items to the table but I just can't remove them.

Thanks :)

Comment: Implement the canEditRowAtIndexPath

Comment: You need to update your question by fixing the posted code. That beginning of the code makes no sense.

Comment: Try to check if you have any gesture recognizer that is consuming the swipe event. (Do you have a sliding menu in your app?). It would be better also if you can update your code.

Comment: @ELKA I do not have any gesture recognizers nor a sliding menu. Updated the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you implement [tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614900-tableview?language=objc) method?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true  
}
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @rmaddy for mentioning that the default value of `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` is `true`, implementing it doesn't solve the problem.

I'm not pretty sure of what are you trying to do from your code snippet, so make sure that you are implementing the following methods ([UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate)):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        toDoList.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        UserDefaults.standard.set(toDoList, forKey: "toDoList")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .delete
}
```

You can also keep the implementation of `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` method:

> Asks the data source to verify that the given row is editable.

So, -for example- if you want to let the first row is not editable, i.e user cannot swipe and delete the first row, you should do somthing like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Make sure that the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` are connected with the ViewController.

Comment: If you don't implement this delegate method, it defaults to `true` so this can't be the problem.

Comment: UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate are connected. I implemented the editingStyleForRowAt indexPath function. Still does not work.